# Retrieve names of elements of a list via lapply

Tags: r

In a list I want to find which element has some specific length
and just print which element is this and to replace its values with
the mean value:

```
A <- c(10)
B <- c(20, 30)
C <- c(40)
D <- c(50)

ll <- list(A, B, C, D)
names(ll) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

Foo <- function(x){
    if (length(x)>1) {
        print() # What should i enter here in order to receive the name of B
        x <- mean(x)
    } else {
        x <- x
    }
}

ll_new <- lapply(ll, Foo)
```

What I should enter in print function in order to receive the name B?

Comment: use `print(x)` instead : here, you are telling to print `ll[][x]` so when you are working with `ll$B`, `x` is `c(2, 3)` and so R prints `ll[][2:3]`, which is actually `ll[2:3]` so elements `B` and `C` (in other words, `R` is just doing what you are telling it to do ;-)  )

Comment: print(x) will give only [1] 2 3 and not $B [1] 2 3

Comment: Yes because I want to receive the name of the position where (2, 3) reside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give what you want:

```
Foo <- function(x){
  if (length(ll[[x]])>1) {
    print(x) 
    x <- mean(ll[[x]])
  } else {
    x <- ll[[x]]
  }
}

ll_new <- lapply(setNames(names(ll), names(ll)), Foo)
# [1] "B"

ll_new
# $A
# [1] 10
# 
# $B
# [1] 25
#
# $C
# [1] 40
#
# $D
# [1] 50
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you a lot Carlos since i didn't new the setNames function.

Comment: Now I see it better, very clever answer